# index.html is missing when generating production build from create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I created my project with Create React App but when deploying to production, the file index.html is missing in `build` folder. I've checked the public folder and the template of `index.html` is still there.

I've used homepage field in package.json but unsucessful

Comment: Launching npm run build or some npm command to compile your bundle in production mode, you only compile javascript to a javascript bundle. After that, you have to link it from your .html page.

Comment: is there an option to include index.html in production build?

Comment: Webpack is a Javascript compiler and module bundler. But you can add a task that copy your .html file in your dist folder when compiling.

Comment: How do you deploy your application to production?

Comment: just running "npm run build" which is the alias of "react-scripts build". In some previous projects it doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with CRA but the reason is react-snapshot (it's failed to create snapshot).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting Question! Could you post screenshot of all the folders and your package.json scripts here? My first guess is that you are developing on windows/Mac machine and havn't really worried about case sensitivity during the development. And now your server is running on ubuntu and really can't find your index.html.

Also open console when you are getting this error and make sure there are no silly mistakes error there too.